# How to add data into hover in Hvplot (bokeh) candlestick without missing-date gaps

Tags: python, bokeh, holoviews, candlestick-chart, hvplot

I have an simple example, run in jupyter notebook:

- hvplot.ohlc without missing-date gaps
- wanted to fix Hover (add Date in the right format, and add Volume info)

packages:

python 3.12
bokeh 3.3.2
hvplot 0.9.0
holoviews 1.18.1

```py
import pandas as pd
import hvplot.pandas

data = pd.DataFrame({
        "Open": [100.00, 101.25, 102.75],
        "High": [104.10, 105.50, 110.00],
        "Low": [94.00, 97.10, 99.20],
        "Close": [101.15, 99.70, 109.50],
        "Volume": [10012, 5000, 18000],
    }, index=[pd.Timestamp("2022-08-01"), pd.Timestamp("2022-08-03"), pd.Timestamp("2022-08-04")])

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
# remove datetime gaps
df = df.reset_index(names="Date")
df['Idx'] = pd.RangeIndex(0, df.shape[0], 1)

# fix hover ------
from bokeh.models import HoverTool

hover = HoverTool(
    tooltips=[
        ('Date', '@Date{%Y-%m-%d}'),
        ('Open', '@Open{0.00}'),
        ('High', '@High{0.00}'),
        ('Low', '@Low{0.00}'),
        ('Close', '@Close{0.00}'),
        ('Volume', '@Volume{0}'),
    ],
    formatters={'@Date': 'datetime'},
    mode='vline'
)
# fix hover ------

ohlc_cols = ["Open", "High", "Low", "Close"]
ohlc = df.hvplot.ohlc(x='Idx', y=ohlc_cols, hover_cols=["Date", *ohlc_cols, "Volume"], tools=[hover])

# fix x tick labels ------
import holoviews as hv
from bokeh.io import show

fig = hv.render(ohlc)
fig.xaxis.major_label_overrides = {
    i: dt.strftime("%b %d") for i, dt in enumerate(df['Date'])
}
# fix x tick labels ------

show(fig)
```

But the output is:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution, or more a workaround, is to manupilate the ColumnDataSource of the first renderer in the bokeh figure.

You can do so b adding the line below:

```py
fig.renderers[0].data_source.data['Volume'] = df['Volume'].values
```

#### Explanation

To understand why the line above is the solution, I want to explain, what `df.hvplot.ohlc()` does.

This function creates a bokeh figure with 2 renderers, the first rederer is for all whiskers, which gets the HoverTool, and the seconde renderer draws the boxes. The DataFrame is converted to a `ColumnsDataSource` in the inside. The `ColumnsDataSource`s don't have any information about the `"Volume"`, because only used columns used by the whiskers and boxes are stored inside the `ColumnDataSource`. The HoverTool can't find information for the `Volumne`, so it prints `???`. But we can extend the source by this information.

#### Minimal Example

I adapted your example, because I think it is simpler, but the downside is, that there is one empty date.

```py
import pandas as pd
import hvplot.pandas
import holoviews as hv
from bokeh.io import show
from bokeh.models import HoverTool

df= pd.DataFrame({
        "Open": [100.00, 101.25, 102.75],
        "High": [104.10, 105.50, 110.00],
        "Low": [94.00, 97.10, 99.20],
        "Close": [101.15, 99.70, 109.50],
        "Volume": [10012, 5000, 18000],
    },
    index=[pd.Timestamp("2022-08-01"), pd.Timestamp("2022-08-03"), pd.Timestamp("2022-08-04")]
)
df.index.name = "Date"

fig = hv.render(ohlc)
# add missing values to the source for the HoverTool
fig.renderers[0].data_source.data['Volume'] = df['Volume'].values
show(fig)
```

#### Output

[image: ohlc plot with extra data for HoverTool]

Comment: Many thanks! Great, that's it! But expected behaviour that `hover_cols` parameter in `ohlc` should be do that instead of this workaround.

Comment: I agree, specifying columns in hvPlot's `hover_cols` _should_ have been sufficient to make them "value dimensions" (using HoloViews terminology). Plus the OHLC plot should be able to accept an additional value dimension if you specify one, without erroring (`y=ohlc_cols + ["Volume"]`). Please open a feature request on github.com/holoviz/hvplot/issues!

Comment: Issue opened https://github.com/holoviz/hvplot/issues/1214